# Extracting the cordinates of rectangles

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have written a code to locate rectangle from an image (where I can draw the rectangular shapes on the image itself). What I want to do right now is to get the cordinates of the rectangular shaped objects on the image. I am using the Rectangle class to get the rectangle information. Is there a way I could do this?

this is the code im using

```
private void ProcessBW(Bitmap bitmap)
{
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
//blobCounter.MinHeight = 6;
//blobCounter.MinWidth = 6;

blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmap);

// create Image Object using rear image byte[]
System.Drawing.Image imageR = (System.Drawing.Image)bitmap;

// Derive BitMap object using Image instance, so that you can avoid the issue
//"a graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format"
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(imageR));

Rectangle[] rects = blobCounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
//Graphics object to draw
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);                  

foreach (Rectangle rect in rects)
{
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
}
pictureBox1.Image = img;
pen.Dispose();
g.Dispose();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The Rectangle class does have left, top, right and bottom (or x, y, width, height) properties if that's what you are asking. If this is not it, could you clarify, give some sample code? What does your program do, does it locate a rectangle in an image, or draws a rectangular shape? I don't understand what the problem is here...

Comment: If you have code to locate the rectangle, surely that will get the coordinates? I don't understand the question.

Comment: hey sorry about that. I have included the code. I can draw the located rectangular shapes on the image. Is there a way I could get the cordinates of the these objects. I am developing a number plate recognition system. all I want to is to filter the rectangular shapes obtained from the image with the number plate width&length ratio.

Comment: As @Tibi mentions rects[i].x and rects[i].y should provide you the coordinates you are looking for. May you clarify the question. Perhaps with an example....

Comment: @Amit what I am saying is I need to filter the rectangular objects in an image of a vehicle so that I could extract the number plate? (Hope this helps!).

Comment: @KendallFrey Is right, if you can already find the rectangle, what is the point of getting the coordinates?

Comment: Also, you never change `img` from `bitmap`, it is always the `Image` type of `bitmap`, you never change it

Comment: @OutLaw Lemur I need the cordinates to extract the rectangular shapes from the image so that I have the number plate location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to retrieve the cordinates of the rectangle. It was pretty stupid of me and I was quite new with C#. The rectangle class provides methods such as x, y, width and height components that would give me  positions of the rectangles